# How do I set a option to selected using styled-components?

Tags: styled-components

How do I use **styled-component attributes** to set the `selected` property of my styled `option` so that the option is selected within the `select` element depending on whether or not the isSelected property is truthy?

Right now I have this:

```
export const MyOption = styled.option.attrs(props => ({
    selected: {props.isSelected ? "selected" : ""}
})``;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got there is actually almost exactly how you do it.

The only thing you need to change is that you are setting the attrs selected to an object using curly-brackets `{}` when you should be using normal brackets `()` to do the logic.

```
export const MyOption = styled.option.attrs(props => ({ 
    selected: (props.isSelected ? "selected" : ""),
 }))``;
```